# Webpack CSS @import issue 'Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)'

Tags: css, webpack, import

i am having an issue with webpack and my css file. Whenever i run "npm start", i get this error :

> ERROR in ./ticker.css 1:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

I read that it requires a loader for css files however i have installed 'style-loader' and 'css-loader' but apparently it still won't work. Any ideas ?

Here is :

webpackconfig, package file, ticker.css file

Thanks guys !

[image: webpack config]

[image: package]

[image: css file]

I tried to delete and recreate the node_modules directory, use raw loader, change the loaders order.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my node.js version wasn't up to date which caused some conflicts with some packages. Think about updates guys. :)